# Using Jquery Unwrap

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where I wrap the span's in divs.

I would like to unwrap the divs when I press the other button.

I have provided a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/oh48rafw/4/

Here is the code:

```
$("#WrapInDiv").click(function() {
    //wrap each span.Foo in it's own div
    $('span.Foo').wrap('<div class="FontSize30 ParentWrapper"/>);
}); 

$("#RemoveWrapDiv").click(function() {        
    //remove the added div wrapper
    $('.div FontSize30 ParentWrapperr').unwrap();
});
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your unwrap code to:

```
$("#RemoveWrapDiv").click(function() {        
    //remove the added div wrapper
    $('span.Foo').unwrap('div.FontSize30.ParentWrapper');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oh48rafw/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  $('span.Foo').unwrap();
```

Insted of

```
 $('.div FontSize30 ParentWrapperr').unwrap();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oh48rafw/7/)